# Home folder has been transformed into an encrypted file

Tags: linux, disk-encryption, chmod, ecryptfs

Hi I have a weird problem, I've never seen before.

I'm running Linux Mint 20.1.

While running a live USB to try to fix a problem with file permissions on my root folder someone suggested I run >

```
chmod -R +X .
```

Now my folder just has two files>

```
Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop
```

And a read me that just says>

```
THIS DIRECTORY HAS BEEN UNMOUNTED TO PROTECT YOUR DATA.From the graphical desktop, click on: "Access Your Private Data"orFrom the command line, run: ecryptfs-mount-private
```

If I try>

```
ecryptfs-mount-private
```

I get>

```
ERROR: Encrypted private directory is not setup properly
```

Before I ran the chmod command I could see the user folder, although I couldn-t open it.

Any ideas?
EDIT: I used: sudo chown USER:USER /media/USER/TARGETDIRECTORY/ -R

It seems to have worked.

Comment: I am pretty sure you effectively recursively set the permissions to your desktop to 400 which means only the owner has limited access (specifically execute).  You should restore the permission to original values.

Comment: Thanks. How do I do that?

I've found some instructions, but I'm not sure where I should run them. 

There are three places that seem relevant:

`/media/newusername/ubuntu/home/.ecryptfs/oldusername/.ecryptfs`

Contains 4 files:
`auto-mount
auto-umount
Private.mnt
Private.sig
wrapped-passphrase`

`/media/newusername/ubuntu/home/.ecryptfs/oldusername/.Private `

Contains tonnes of encrypted files and directories

`/media/newusername/ubuntu/home/oldusername`
Contains 4 files, 1 directory:

.cache
Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop
README.txt
.ecryptfs
.Private

Comment: How do you do what? Based on the paths of the user file, you most certainly are using encrypted file system, which changes my assumption(s).

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. 
How do I restore the permissions to default?

Yes, I had an encrypted directory, but it looked like a folder previously, now it looks like a link. 

I think the problem is that the command has revoked permissions from the keys and files related to the home directory encryption, resulting in the current situation. 

So I need a way to restore the default permissions for all the files involved in the encryption/decryption process. 

I think the easiest way would be to set liberal permissions for the whole drive, but I don't know how to do that. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think the permissions part of this problem has been solved. Cheers!

Comment: @Ramhound - your *pretty sure* above is wrong. `chmod -R +X` doesn't set 400 on all files and directories, it makes every directory readable/searchable to everyone.

Comment: @ClosupJofre - for others sake who made the same mistake - what did you have to do to resolve it? Take `x` away from the encrypted directory for group and other?

Comment: And for other's sake who stumble upon this - some more background: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76256765/i-need-help-to-restore-permissions-to-root-folder-after-chmod

Comment: I used:
sudo chown USER:USER /media/USER/TARGETDIRECTORY/ -R

Comment: @tink - I thought R and W handled Read and Write permissions while X was Execute permissions on the folder. I suppose at the worse the command would have added Execute permissions, not remove whatever Read and Write, permissions were already set.

Comment: @ClosupJofre - You will want to [edit] your question so users following your question can be notified of changes to it.

Comment: @Ramhound - that is indeed correct. :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the author has indicated they solved their own problem.

Comment: OP should have been advised to post an answer to their question instead of being told to edit their question to add the answer to it.